# Wordpress query_posts order DESC not working

Tags: wordpress

In this snippet the `order=DESC` and `orderby=date` clauses seems to be ignored.
I checked the code and the part `'&orderby=date&order=DESC'` seems correct.
`var_dump` still return posts in wrong order.
Tried to order by `ID, post_title, title, date and modified`, the order returned simply does not change at all... These parameters are ignored.

```
$latest_posts = query_posts('post_type=' . $post_type . '&cat=' . $category . '&terms=' . $terms . '&posts_per_page=' . $number . '&orderby=date&order=DESC');
var_dump($latest_posts);
```

Comment: In my case still not work.

Comment: Maybe a bug http://wordpress.org/support/topic/query_posts-and-order-by-date

Comment: No! It doesn't work with any field! Won't work with ID, title, post_title etc... Also the link you shared is a six years old thread

Answer (score 0):

Specify the column name for sorted order. Now you are entering wrong.
 So use `post_date` instead of `date`

```
$latest_posts = query_posts('post_type=' . $post_type . '&cat=' . $category . '&terms=' . $terms . '&posts_per_page=' . $number . '&orderby=post_date&order=DESC');
var_dump($latest_posts);
```

Comment: In my case does not work... Tried even with ID field... I may send you access to my code if you like.

Comment: you want to display some posts with specific category. right?

Comment: Yes, and I did this. I simply want to revert the order. No code on the codex works. I also tried to empty my functions.php file to be sure no hooks are breaking things. Also tried to temporary disable all plugins.